# how to create a file inside the django template

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, django-templates

i am generating the google charts and converting them into the image by using getimageuri() method. this method returns a url and now i need to store that url into file.
i dont know how to create a file inside the django template and how to store data into it.
following is my chart genearting code in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Job-Names', 'Pass', 'Fail'],
             {{data.0.0|safe}}
]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Jenkins Job Details for project {{data.0.1}}',
      vAxis: {title: "Job Names" , textStyle : {fontSize : 10} },
      hAxis: {title: "Number of Builds" , ticks : [2,4,6,8,10] },
      is3D: true,
  width: 1250,
  height: 550,
      colors : ["#008000", "#cc0000"],
      pointSize: 4

    };

    var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chart_div);

// Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
imageurl = chart.getImageURI()


 });

    chart.draw(data, options);


    //var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    //table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false});
  }

 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

that imageurl i need to store into the file.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The getimageuri() actually return the file itself, uriencoded, which looks like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
```

If you want to store this image server side, you have to send it to the server, preferably using AJAX, and then processing on server side by throwing away the text before the `,` including, and then creating an image file from the base64 string using django's File functions.

Comment: but i just need to create this url into the file. Is there any way to do it..?/

Comment: you want to store it client side?

Comment: in above code i am getting the imageurl and now i just want to store it tinto the file.

Comment: If you read my answer I wrote it crystal clear, there's no secret button to to that, you have to implement it, and that's not a URL, that image data stored in a URIencoded string.